# Custom UIPageControl currentPage's Dot

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I get the dots of  UIPageControl, and to change its size? I just wanna make a Animation(small to big) when the currentPage's dot appears.

Comment: NSUInteger currentIndex = [[self.pageViewController.viewControllers lastObject] index];   you can get currentPage with this line of code...

Comment: sorry, it's UIPageControl instead of UIPageViewController...

Comment: Create your own, you can't change size of the existing dots.

Comment: Is there a good demo? I have no idea about it...

Comment: Use this https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXPageControl